Why is nginx ignores .js files, but all other endpoints work good?
I have this one nginx conf:
# Default server definition
server {
    listen [::]:8080 default_server;
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name _;

    tcp_nodelay on;
    absolute_redirect off;
    
    #this one works perfectly, it is webserver+ws by its own implementation
    location /backend/firstws {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 1d; # dont kill connection after 60s of inactivity
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7898/;
    }

    #this one also, no any issues, it is pure ws server on nodejs
    location /backend/secondws/ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 1d; # dont kill connection after 60s of inactivity
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/;
    }

    #and here i'm trying to proxify requests to noVNC via NGINX.
    location /backend/vnc/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5800/;
    }

    # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /var/lib/nginx/html;
    }

    # Set the cache-control headers on assets to cache for 3 hours
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        expires 1h;
    }

    # Deny access to . files, for security
    location ~ /\. {
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

}

This block is somewhy wrong:
    #and here i'm trying to proxify requests to noVNC via NGINX.
    location /backend/vnc/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5800/;
    }

It proxifies index.html perfectly, directories, but thats hapenning when trying to load any js files:
Directory - ok:
Image 1
And js file in directory - 404??? how? here it is:
Image 2
I've tried a lot with try_files, no one works.
Now i've placed all assets before nginx, it works, but it is not a best way, because it requires to rewrite conf file when assets are changing.
I'm expecting that all files, not only directories will be served by nginx with no any problems.
Will be very glad to listen to nginx specialists. Thank you all for your time, even if you only read my question!

See how Nginx processes a request.
When Nginx receives the URL /backend/vnc/foo.js, it will search for a location to process the request.
The regular expression \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ matches the URL, and therefore the location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ is used to process the request.
Although location /backend/vnc/ also matches the URL, the regular expression locations take precedence.
To override this behaviour, use the ^~ operator, for example:
location ^~ /backend/vnc/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5800/;
}

The ^~ means that this prefix location will take precedence over any regular expression location.
If you still need to use the expires directive on some URL patterns, use a map (see this example) to avoid breaking the location search.
